# Consider the equation: $x^4 = y^2 -9$. Number of positive integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are two solutions I found:

- $x = 0, y = 3$
- $x = 2, y = 5$

I checked this with Wolfram|Alpha – reportedly, these are the only integer solutions for this equations. So it's cool that I have them, but how do I know/prove that these are the only ones?

I assume this is something elementary, but I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 3):

You have $y^2 = x^4+9$ and $x^4$ is a perfect square.  Then next perfect square after $x^4$ is $(x^2+1)^2 = x^4+2x^2+1$.  So if $2x^2+1$ is bigger than $9$, you can't have a solution.  So $x\leq 2.$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$x^4=y^2-9 \iff$$

$$y^2-x^4=9 \iff$$

$$(y-x^2)(y+x^2)=1.9=3.3$$

The sum of factors is

$$2y=1+9=10$$ or
$$2y=3+3=6$$

this gives
$$y=5\;\;\;x=2$$
or
$$y=3 \;\;\;x=0$$